# Bootstrap 4: Don’t want dropdown items inside the navbar container

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

When I collapse the screen, I don’t want the dropdown items to be inside the navbar. In the drop-down menu, I positioned it as an absolute. The only problem is that some of the items in the drop-down list get cut off and I don't want the scroll bar to be there. I tried to use media queries to manually move it but the position of it doesn’t change.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark py-0 ">
    <a class="navbar-brand py-0" href="#">Navbar</a>

    <ul class="ml-auto navbar-nav ml-auto">

        <li class=" mt-auto mb-auto nav-item active py-0 d-none d-xl-block d-lg-block ">
            <a class="nav-link " href="#">Hi, username <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>

        <li class="mt-auto mb-auto nav-item dropdown py-0">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle py-0" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown"
                aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" type="submit"><img src="images/space_stars_blue_free_wallpaper.jpg"
                        class="img-fluid rounded-circle " alt="..." width="45" height="45"></button>
            </a>

            <div id="test1" class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right position-absolute" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>

                </div>


        </li>

    </ul>

</nav>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fby71cm2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not seeing the scroll bar problem. Maybe that's because we don't have access to `images/space_stars_blue_free_wallpaper.jpg`.

You can move the menu left by adding this CSS:

```
#test1 {
  left:auto;
  right: 0;
}
```